# NullPointerException during JAXBContext.newInstance(contextPath) - jakarta.xml.bind

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, nullpointerexception, jaxb, xml-binding

In my maven based project, String "contextPath" is nothing but any package of my project. No matter what package(or multiple packages appended with :) i assign to contextPath, i still get NullPointerException.

So i get NullPointerException during , JAXBContext.newInstance(contextPath).

```
import jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
...
private String contextPath = "com.abc.core"; 
...
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(contextPath);
```

Even if that contextPath is

```
"com.abc.core:com.bcd:core"
```

Or whatsoever, i get nullpointer always.

In my pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

I am expecting at least JAXBException, but getting NullPointerException always. Note that i am using jakarta.xml.bind and not javax.xml.bind. And using jdk 8.

I have tried upgrading jakarta.xml.bind to 3.0.1 , but still seeing the same issue. Tried checking mvn dependency:tree to check if someone else is forcing some other version of jakarta.xml.bind to use , but didn't get any clue from there.

I checked the docs of jakarta.xml.bind for JAXBContext, but as per doc i should get JAXBException if contextPath is not proper. - [docs for JAXBContext](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/xml-binding/3.0/apidocs/jakarta.xml.bind/jakarta/xml/bind/jaxbcontext#newInstance(java.lang.String,java.lang.ClassLoader))
But instead, i always get a nullpointer.

Can you please let me know what might be the reason for this NullPointer?

Comment: seeing as we have no idea which part causes the NPE, how do you want us to respond?

Comment: As i have already mentioned, i have confirmed that the nullpointer is thrown right there when i call JAXBContext.newInstance(contextPath). I have imported jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBContext and contextPath here can be any package , no matter what package i give there, i get a nullpointer always.

Comment: so, you mean to say that a static method call is throwing the NPE? Seems unlikely, since JAXBContext can't be null.

Comment: Yeah correct, that is the strange part here. I have printed debug logs right before and after that line , and confirmed that this static method call itself is throwing NPE. For some reason JAXBContext is not loading. 

Can you please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4566672/nullpointerexception-in-jaxbcontext-newinstance ? Here also the same thing was reported , but with very old version. And  here the OP had mentioned that some other pom.xml was causing the issue.

Comment: if you had looked at that stacktrace there, you would understand that it's not that line itself that throws the NPE

Comment: The moment i call this even in a System.out.print("xyz: "+JAXBContext.newInstance(xontextPath)) , i hit nullpointer.  All logs before that line gets printed and the next line from this above sop line doesn't get printed.

Comment: and your point is? Have you checked the stacktrace?

Comment: You're correct. When i put that statement in try catch block, i found that NoClassDefFound error was seen as it was expecting org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime but wasn't finding. When i added it in pom.xml , the classdefnotfound error is gone now. However am seeing the below error now and am trying to figure out the below issue now.

Comment: Two classes have the same XML type name "objectFactory". Use XmlType.name and XmlType.namespace to assign different names to them.
 this problem is related to the following location:
  at com.abc.model.ObjectFactory
 this problem is related to the following location:
  at com.bcd.core.ObjectFactory

........
org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException$Builder.check(IllegalAnnotationsException.java:76)
 at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:419)

Answer (score 0):

The exception was not due to NullPointer during JAXBContext.newInstance(contextPath) , but a NoClassDefFound error due to absence of a dependent lib org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime. When i added this to the pom.xml , the issue got resolved.